# Ensure we're found in Facebook search for both full & abbreviated company names?

Tags: facebook, search, optimization

We have a client with a facebook page, let's say his company is called  **Bob Roberts Super Widgets**. And if you search in Facebook for Bob Roberts Super Widgets then up he pops.

But the shorthand he's commonly known by is **BR Super Widgets** and indeed the website we've created for him is br-super-widgets.com.

In Facebook, searching for BR Super Widgets doesn't show up our Mr Bob. We don't have a lot of Facebook expertise, so asking for help here. Does anyone know how to ensure you're found in Facebook search for both short and long company names?

Have found this [this similar question](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=42328360008&topic=19406) in the Facebook forum but the poor old questioner never got a response.

Answer (score 1):

The two keys to being found on Facebook are:

- Optimizing the page (especially the page title)
- Getting Followers

Be sure that your page says both versions of the company name multiple times and them suggest your page to people who have an interest in your niche and company.

Are you showing up for the long version of the page?

Comment: yes if you search in Facebook for Bob Roberts Super Widgets then up he pops

Comment: when you say "the Page", where does it need to go? the About section? the wall? in the address?